# Python: calculate time car uses between two points

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to write a program that reads input from two files (box_a.txt and box_b.txt). The two files contains information from two speed cameras: the license plate number and the time the car passed box a and box b (f.eks GWU2019, 2019-02-04 09:22:57). My goal is that the user inputs a a license plate number (variable 'license' below), the program checks in both files, lists the time the car has passed box a and calculates the time (in minutes) the car has used between box a and box b. Further I would like it to calculate the average speed also, but I can look into that later. I am struggeling to get the code right, and the attempt below seems to have several errors. Any ideas?

```
def fileToDictionary(file):

    filename = file
    filename = open(file, 'r')
    readings = []

    for line in filename:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        reg = line.split(', ')
        readings.append(reg)
    filename.close()

    dictionary = dict(readings)

    for key in dictionary:
        print(key, ' : ', dictionary[key])

def listSpeeders():
    filename_a = "box_a.txt"
    filename_b = "box_b.txt"
    speed_limit = 60
    distance = 10

    license = input("Enter the licence plate number: ")
    timePassBoxA = dictionary[licensefileToDictionary(filename_a)]
    timeBetweenBoxAandBoxB = dictionary[licensefileToDictionary(filename_b)] - dictionary[licensefileToDictionary(filename_a)]
    
    print(license + " passed speed camera box a at " + timePassBoxA + " and it used " + timeBetweenBoxAandBoxB + " minutes between the two boxes" )
    
listSpeeders()
```

Comment: "the attempt below seems to have several errors"

It would be very helpful if you posted the errors

Answer (score 0):

So, you can convert your values from dict to `datetime.datetime`, and then substract one from another

```
import datetime


def file_to_dictionary(file):
    filename = file
    filename = open(file, 'r')
    readings = []

    for line in filename:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        reg = line.split(', ')
        readings.append(reg)
    filename.close()

    dictionary = dict(readings)

    for key in dictionary:
        print(key, ' : ', dictionary[key])

    return dictionary


date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'


def list_speeders():
    filename_a = "box_a.txt"
    filename_b = "box_b.txt"

    dict_a = file_to_dictionary(filename_a)
    dict_b = file_to_dictionary(filename_b)

    license_ = input()

    a_time = dict_a[license_]
    b_time = dict_b[license_]

    print((datetime.datetime.strptime(b_time, date_format) - datetime.datetime.strptime(a_time,
                                                                                        date_format)).total_seconds())
```

**NOTE**

I edited code, so `file_to_dictionary` returns produced dictionary. I did also format variable and methods names. Please follow PEP8 style conventions, do not call methods with CamelCase, only classes usually called via CamelCase, use snake_case for variables and methods (`fileToDictionary` -> `file_to_dictionary`, `listSpeeders` -> `list_speeders`). Also do not use builtin function names as global or context variables (`license` -> `license_`), so you will always be able to use builtins with no need to change your namings sometimes after

Comment: Thanks very much @sudden_appearance ! When I am trying to run the code I only get dictionary with the license plate nr and time oss passing box a. Do you know how to i get to print the license nr + time om passing box 1 and the minutes between them?